# How to iterate into a list on django relation one-to-many

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, models

I'm new on this forum and in django.
I'm using Python 2.7 environment.

I have the following models.py:

```
class Categoria(models.Model):

    DEFAULT_CATHEGORY = 0
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, default='0')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome

class Produto(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pontos_na_compra = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, default=0)
    pontos_na_troca = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=10, default=0)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)

    categoria = models.ForeignKey(
        Categoria,
        default=Categoria.DEFAULT_CATHEGORY
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.nome, self.codigo_depara)
```

I want the relation: each Categoria (cathegory) has many Produto (products). Is it correct in the model?
I don't have anything on views.py relationed to it.

I want to do some code like this into HTML file:

```
 show CATEGORIA.nome 

    for each PRODUTO in LIST OF PRODUCTS IN CATEGORIA do:

       show PRODUTO.nome

       show PRODUTO.pontos_na_compra

       show PRODUTO.foto

    end-for
```

I try to use

```
{% if categorias %}
  <ul id="flexisel">
  {% for categoria in produto.categoria_set() %}
    <li>
      # SHOW ALL HERE. HOW?
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  <p id="flexise">
     Nenhum produto encontrado!
  </p>
{% endif %}
```

But it didn't find the categoria_set() method and returns this:

> Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'produto.categoria_set()'
>
> Request Method:    GET
>      Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>      Django Version:    1.9.2
>      Exception Type:    TemplateSyntaxError
>      Exception Value:
>
> Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'produto.categoria_set()'
>
> Exception Location:    /home/dsbonafe/.virtualenvs/bruno/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in parse, line 516
>      Python Executable:     /home/dsbonafe/.virtualenvs/bruno/bin/python
>      Python Version:    2.7.6
>      Python Path:
>
> ['/home/dsbonafe/Documentos/Projetos/Bruno Mercado/bruno/redewebsite',
>        '/home/dsbonafe/.virtualenvs/bruno/lib/python2.7',
>        '/home/dsbonafe/.virtualenvs/bruno/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>        '/home/dsbonafe/.virtualenvs/bruno/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>        '/home/dsbonafe/.virtualenvs/bruno/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>        '/home/dsbonafe/.virtualenvs/bruno/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>        '/usr/lib/python2.7',
>        '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>        '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>        '/home/dsbonafe/.virtualenvs/bruno/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>        '/home/dsbonafe/.virtualenvs/bruno/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>
> Server time:   Ter, 23 Fev 2016 20:55:39 +0000

Someone could help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I misread something in your question.  You seem to contradict yourself.  In your explanation you said you wanted a Categoria to have many Produtos.  In your template code, you do a lookup: `produto.categoria_set`.  That's the reverse.  Which one do you intend?  Is your template code wrong?  I can update my answer.

Comment: In fact, I had not understood the categoria_set. The follow answer, show me what happend.

Answer (score 1):

Your model looks correct to me.  I see a couple of potential problems.

1. Depending on your templating engine, you might have to drop the parenthesis.  I think Jinja2 uses them but Django Template Language does not.  I think, based on the error message, you're using the latter (DTL).
2. You probably just need to call the `all` method on `produto.categoria_set`.  I'm pretty sure `categoria_set` is a kind of manager object.  You need a QuerySet, which will be returned when you call `all`.

Here's what you should try:

```
{% for categoria in produto.categoria_set.all %}
# SHOW ALL HERE. HOW?
{% endfor %}
```

*Note: this answer is currently in flux because the original question contradicts itself.*